# Open directly a web page from a button in Ribbon in a browser outside Excel?

Tags: excel, office-js

We have several Excel add-ins in AppSource. At the moment, we have a button in Ribbon for `Documentation`, clicking on the button opens the documentation webpage in a taskpane in Excel.

We feel that as the taskpane is small, people are unlikely to read documentation over there. So a better way would be to open the documentation webpage in a browser outside Excel.

We notice that in Script Lab, clicking on the `Reference Docs` opens a small window which contains `open link in new window`. Then, we need to click on that link to finally open that in a browser:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/774409/81099107-ab068e80-8f0a-11ea-9633-eba5c1e42f90.png

So do we have to have this intermediate window? Cannot we open directly a web page from a button  in Ribbon in a browser outside Excel?

PS: I don't want to use Dialog API to show documentation, because it seems that when the Dialog window is open, we cannot use Excel at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In manifest, you could make it UI less, and specifies the source code file for operations that an add-in exposes through add-in commands that execute a JavaScript function instead of displaying UI，

```
<DesktopFormFactor>
  <FunctionFile resid="residDesktopFuncUrl" />
  <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
    <!-- information about this extension point -->
  </ExtensionPoint>        
</DesktopFormFactor>
```

and in the FunctionFile you could add a function, which can call `Office.context.ui.openBrowserWindow(url)` to launch the URL in the default browser outside of excel

```
Office.context.ui.openBrowserWindow("https://github.com");
```

The document can be found at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/functionfile), which describes how to implement the function defined by FunctionName in the manifest.

Comment: What should I put in the manifest file? I guess I should not put `Office.context.ui.openBrowserWindow(url)` directly in the manifest file.

Comment: no, not in manifest, just provide the sample code. you could try it in scriptlab

Comment: I'm not sure you understand my question... I want to know how to open a webpage in a browser **directly from a button in the ribbon**.

Comment: Sorry, I misread it, I thought the main question is to launch the browser outside of excel. 
i just update the answer. you could use the UI Less function file.

Comment: Yes, I want to launch the browser outside Excel. I will try that, thank you...