# Close open Desktop Taskpane using office.js or Add-in manifest function

Tags: excel, ms-office, office-js, add-in

We have created add-in manifest xml file for our application and also embed office.js file.
We have use custom ribbon feature by assigning url to icon. When we click on icon, it open task pane on desktop. We want to open third party url in new window of browser using Add-in manifest and taskpane should be close. 
We have gone through AppDomains and uses Office.addin.hide function. But both solutions are not working.
Please provide us solution if exist.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried Office.addin.hide() function in application and also Appdomains tag  in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Office.js doesn't provide anything for opening a new tab in a web browser. Instead, you can display a popup message. In Excel, you can use the following code to hide the task pane:

```
 Office.addin.hide();
```

For example:

```
function onCurrentQuarterDeactivated() {
    Office.addin.hide();
}
```

See [Show or hide an Office Add-in in a shared runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/show-hide-add-in) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use UI less function, in UI less function, you could execute a javascript code to open a page in the default browser.

You could refer to this answer. 
[Open directly a web page from a button in Ribbon in a browser outside Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61736702/open-directly-a-web-page-from-a-button-in-ribbon-in-a-browser-outside-excel/61809574#61809574)